# How to remove charset="iso-8859-1" inside Content-Type of generated EML file from outbound email

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. The EML files generated by outbound mailer service is contains **Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"** we want to remove charset="iso-8859-1" from Content-Type header.is there any setting in outboundemail configuration file to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to remove it? Knowing the character set used is quite important for e-mail clients to display it correctly. Do you perhaps mean to change it to something else?

Comment: @PeterKjaer Perhaps the right question here is to know what determines the charset of an email generated by Outbound Email. The publication used for Emails has UTF-8 defined as the encoding (Default Code Page). Emails are being generated in English and Arabic (separate emails for the 2 languages). However the generated eml files have charset=iso-8859-1 defined which causes issues with some email clients.

Comment: Indeed, that makes a lot of sense :) I'll submit an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is determined by Chilkat based on the content. It is, unfortunately, a bit of a black box. Sometimes that detection fails and it picks the wrong encoding. That appears to be the case for you.

Luckily, we built in an override for just such a situation. You can set the `FixedEncoding` element in *OutboundEmail.xml* to an encoding that will work for all of your e-mails (e.g. UTF-8).

Here is a link to the documentation page for the setting: [Configuring outgoing e-mail](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-753EC8EC-2A83-4D98-9DAD-277478A5B5FE)